# encoding on special characters lost when doing pd.read_msgpack(df.to_msgpack())

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, character-encoding

I have encountered an encoding issue with special characters when using msgpack() for intermediate caching. The issue can be demonstrated as follows

```
ipdb> df
                                          diff    zscore
    variable    code
    pdl_comeg_n - bitte wählen Sie aus -     0  1.072795


ipdb> pd.read_msgpack(df.to_msgpack())
                                       diff    zscore
variable    code
pdl_comeg_n - bitte wÃ¤hlen Sie aus -     0  1.072795
```

I attempted to stipulate utf8 encoding as a work around but this still did not do the trick

```
ipdb> pd.read_msgpack(df.to_msgpack(encoding='utf8'), encoding='utf8')
                                       diff    zscore
variable    code
pdl_comeg_n - bitte wÃ¤hlen Sie aus -     0  1.072795
```

I used chardet to detect the encoding of the string and tried to decode it as follows but no glory

```
chardet.detect(df.to_msgpack())
{'confidence': 0.6422512189330332, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2'}
ipdb> pd.read_msgpack(df.to_msgpack(), encoding='ISO-8859-2')
                                       diff    zscore
variable    code
pdl_comeg_n - bitte wÃ¤hlen Sie aus -     0  1.072795
any suggestions ? would be much appreciated
```

Comment: I suspect you need to "guess" the original encoding to read it correctly. Try running `chardet` on the file first.

Comment: You didn't specify, but this is fixed in pandas 0.17.0: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/10686 (you do need to specify the encoding)

Comment: any idea's on a work around for now guys ? We can't update our version of pandas atm

Comment: no work-around, this required updating the msgpack version which was actually a bit tricky.